# How to combine two if statements into one?

Tags: javascript, validation

I know there is a much cleanlier way to write this than multiple if statements but when I try to combine them my validation stops working! This isn't good practice right? Or in this case is two different if statements okay?

My code:

```
function validateForm() {
    var success = true;
    var x = document.forms["contestForm"]["firstName"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {

        addClass($('#firstNamespan'), 'formError');
        removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
        success = false;
    } else {
        removeClass($('#firstNamespan'), 'formError');
        addClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
    }

    var x = document.forms["contestForm"]["lastName"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
        addClass($('#lastNamespan'), 'formError');
        removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
        success = false;
    } else {
        removeClass($('#lastNamespan'), 'formError');        
    }
    return success;
}
```

My attempt to combine:

```
function validateForm() {
    var success = true;
    var x = document.forms["contestForm"]["firstName", "lastName"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
        addClass($('#firstNamespan', '#lastNamespan'), 'formError');
        removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
        success = false;
    } else {
        removeClass($('#firstNamespan', '#lastNamespan'), 'formError');
    }
    return success;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? I also will need to add a birthday and e-mail validation but I wanted to get this cleaned up first before it became a monster of if else statements! Sorry for the extra non-helpful information its making me write more because I have to much code. Please feel free to edit and delete this once its posted.

Comment: you best be renaming those variables, JS gone get confused with declaring variable `x` twice

Comment: You probably can't simply list selectors like that without using jQuery or some other library. You'd have to put your selectors in an array and loop through them.

Comment: check the console for any JS errors, e.g. invalid assignment of variable `x`

Comment: Instead of `document.forms["contestForm"]["firstName"].value` you should use `document.forms.contestForm.elements.firstName.value`. Without `elements` it may work on some browsers, but it isn't the standard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Combine them by functional programming:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["contestForm"]["firstName"].value;
    //calls the function checkObject with the object x and the id
    var success1 = checkObject(x, '#firstNamespan');
    //the result of success1 is either true or false.

    var x = document.forms["contestForm"]["lastName"].value;
    //calls the function checkObject with the object x and the id
    var success2 = checkObject(x, '#lastNamespan');
    //the result of success2 is either true or false.

    //returns true if both success1 and success2 are true, otherwise returns false.
    return success1 && success2;
}

function checkObject(x, id)
{
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        addClass($(id), 'formError');
        removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
        return false;
    } else {
        removeClass($(id), 'formError');        
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

### Which could then be condensed into

```
function validateForm() {
    return checkObject($('form[name="frmSave"] #firstName').val(), '#firstNamespan') && checkObject($('form[name="frmSave"] #lastName').val(), '#lastNamespan');
}

function checkObject(x, id)
{
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        addClass($(id), 'formError');
        removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
        return false;
    } else {
        removeClass($(id), 'formError');        
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

### Answer for N number of fields with your pattern of naming

```
function validateForm() {
    var itemsToValidate = ["#firstName", "#lastName", "#birthday", "#email"];
    var results = [];
    $.map( itemsToValidate, function( val, i ) {
        results.push(checkObject($('form[name="frmSave"] ' + val).val(), val + 'span'));
    });

    for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
    {
        if(results[i] == false)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function checkObject(x, id)
{
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        addClass($(id), 'formError');
        removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
        return false;
    } else {
        removeClass($(id), 'formError');        
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't validate any of the JavaScript above please call me out if i made a mistake.  I just typed this up in notepad as i'm out the door at work

Comment: Just make sure var success is in the outter scope so that both functions can access it!

Comment: @frenchie good catch, better yet i'll return it...i think my bitwise math is right there.

Comment: return success1 | success2; should return (success1 && success2); because you want both to be true in order for the validation to be true.

Comment: While you certainly have created a function, the validateForm function  requires modification each time an additional field is added, per the question they need to also validate birthday, email, etc...

Comment: @Hayes I didn't read that part, i think i'd use an array if that's the case.

Comment: This works perfectly! But whats this about an array instead? Will it give me trouble when I try to add birthday and email?

Comment: @user3205098 The array is above it should make it easier to continually add N number of items to this.

Comment: Hmmm, the array one didn't work. But the validation for email and birthday are going to be a lot stricter so thats alright. I can make a different statement for them. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Break things up into functions and utilize an array to loop through the fields to validate.

```
function isValidField(fieldName) {
    var value = document.forms["contestForm"][fieldName].value;
    return !(value == null || value == "");
}

function displayFieldError(fieldName) {
    addClass($('#' + fieldName + 'span'), 'formError');
    removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
}

var fields = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
var isValidForm = true;

fields.map(function(fieldName) {
    if (!isValidField(fieldName)) {
        displayFieldError(fieldName);
        isValidForm = false;
    }
});

if (isValidForm) {
    // Form is correct, do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By giving them a seperate identifier like this

```
var x = document.forms["contestForm"]["firstName"].value;
var y = document.forms["contestForm"]["lastName"].value;

if ((x == null || x == "") && (y == null || y == "")) {

    addClass($('#firstNamespan'), 'formError');
    removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');

    addClass($('#lastNamespan'), 'formError');
    removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
    success = false;

} else {
    removeClass($('#firstNamespan'), 'formError');
    addClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');

    removeClass($('#lastNamespan'), 'formError');        
}
```

But you need to be more precise about, what would you do with just `addClass`? That won't work. You need have a JS object before this method call.

I think, you want some element there before the `addClass` and `removeClass`. Or they need to be like this

```
$('#firstNamespan').removeClass('formError');
```

Like this, you need to change your code. So that the object comes first and then the method call.

Comment: For every field that needs to be added he'd need to add an additional criteria to the if statement.  I think that defeats the point of his request.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function,

```
function validateForm(formName) {
  var x =  document.forms["contestForm"][formName].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    addClass($('#' + formName + 'span'), 'formError');
    removeClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
    return false;
  }
  removeClass($('#' + formName + 'span'), 'formError');
  addClass($('.validationError'), 'is-hidden');
  return true;
}
```

then you can call it twice,

```
function validateForm() {
  var success = validateForm('firstName');
  if (success) {
    success = validateForm('lastName');
  }
  return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two ifs are checking two different form elements, and showing and hiding two different validation error elements.

Combining them will not be just a code refactor but also change functionality.

The only thing they have in common are that they both use the same variable 'x'.